# Android Parse push notification not working in Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I'm trying to create a simple push notification application using parse, here is the code that I've used from the [documentation](https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/new):

```
package com.parse.starter;

import android.app.Application;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseACL;
import com.parse.ParseCrashReporting;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

public class ParseApplication extends Application {

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Initialize Crash Reporting.
    ParseCrashReporting.enable(this);

    // Enable Local Datastore.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    // Add your initialization code here
    Parse.initialize(this, "-", "-");


    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    // Optionally enable public read access.
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
  }
}
```

Activity:

```
public class ParseStarterProjectActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.parse.starter"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!--
      IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
      to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
    -->
    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
        android:name="com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".ParseApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:allowBackup="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".ParseStarterProjectActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <!--
                  IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
                -->
                <category android:name="com.parse.starter" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I try to send push notifications using the parse.com website console, but I dont receive anything in the app. Am I missing a part of the code?

EDIT: My package name is "com.parse.starter"!! its in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: "IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name." -- did you read this? You didn't do it.

Answer (score 6):

For whatever reason, Parse has two tutorials; one is complete and the other isn't. Guess which one you found.

The complete one is here:
https://www.parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications

Essentially, you are missing step 5. In your `Application` class, in the `onCreate` method...

```
ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
  @Override
  public void done(ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
      Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
    } else {
      Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: the link is outdated

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest it clearly says...

```
<!--
  IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
  to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
-->
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

and

```
                <!--
              IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
            -->
            <category android:name="com.parse.starter" />
```

Comment: I kept the same package name... its clearly shown in the android manifest xml

Comment: The code in this documentation says its enough to receive the push notification: https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/new

Answer (score 1):

- Go to this [parse create new application](https://www.parse.com/apps).Enter your application name and
  click create app.
- Then go to settings in that app.Copy your application id and client
  key and paste it in your code.
- Then you have to `enable` the `Client push` in settings->push.
- Click Push->send a push ->Push Quick
  Start->Android->Native(Java)->Existing Project->Then you have to
  follow all the instructions placed in this [Quick Start Link](https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/native/existing).
- You have to add the parse 1.9.3 jar in File ->project structure ->App
  ->Dependencies-> + ->File Depency ->add the parse 1.9.3 jar.

The **Application** Class have to be like this:

```
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
import com.parse.PushService;

public class Application extends android.app.Application {

  public Application() {

  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Initialize the Parse SDK.
    Parse.initialize(this, "", "");  //app id and client key
    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

You can see the verification here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your `Application` class, paste this:

```
Parse.initialize(this, "...", "...");
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

The 2nd line is missing. This is a similar solution to Murkaeus's answer.

Source: https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/native/new