# Android Parse push notifications not received even when subscribed

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28518803/android-parse-push-notification-not-working-in-android), and although my problem seems similar, I have everything set up properly, here's the relevant java:

```
    Parse.initialize(this, "MY_KEY", "MY_KEY");
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

    ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {

            // callback to confirm subscription

            if (e == null) {
                Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
            } else {
                Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
            }
        }
    });
```

Anyways, looking at my dashboard on parse.com the subscription is being recognized and when I attempt to send the push it says "sending to 2 devices" (my phone and a virtual machine). It then shows up with a green check mark on the list of sent pushes BUT under "pushes sent" it says 0.

It also seems that sometimes, deviceToken and pushType are not being set properly, but there hasn't been any difference in effect whether these are present are not, although I'm assuming they are necessary.

How is not sending any pushes to subscribed devices a success?

My manifest can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/allthetime/64630baf4f807f45c59b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that all the XML manifest is correct, try this:

```
> Parse.initialize(this, "MY_KEY", "MY_KEY");
> ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());       
> ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("");//Optionaly put your callback
> PushService.startServiceIfRequired(getApplicationContext());
>  
> ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

Comment: my manifest is here: https://gist.github.com/allthetime/64630baf4f807f45c59b would u mind reviewing it?

Comment: Hey, this worked for me. Its a shame that this isn't in the Parse tutorial. Can you by any chance explain why this works and my original doesn't?

Comment: I don't know exactly. I just used the official documentation of more recently version. But does not worked for me. So, I used the documentation of older versions that work and replace deprecated methods.