# Not receiving any parse push notifications in Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

So I've been trying to set up Parse's push notifications.  I've followed the tutorial as well as other threads on SO but just can't get it to work.  Any help would great.  I have multiple product flavors so I can't statically put the package name (or can I?.....).  I'm able to send push notifications from the parse dashboard, but I am not receiving any notifications on my phone.

Application.class

```
ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
        ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

        ParseCrashReporting.enable(this);

        Parse.initialize(this, "xxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxx");


        ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
        ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();


        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
        ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
            }
        });
```

Manifest

```
 <!--
  IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
  to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
-->
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

  <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <!--
              IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
            -->
            <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured out how to get it to work, BUT - I can't explain why.  I got the answer from this thread [Working Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31307656/android-parse-push-notifications-not-received-even-when-subscribed?rq=1).

@Juven_v answer was correct.